# sort mysql data php

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

eh, I have a problem with filters, I create filter for price range, but I need sort that data to asc or desc?

How I can cake up that thing?

Here my code for price range.

```
if(isset($_POST['sort'])) {

    $cena_no = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['fl_cena_no']));
    $cena_lidz = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['fl_cena_lidz']));    

    if(empty($cena_lidz)){
        $cena_lidz = '99999999999999999999999999999999';
    }

    if(empty($cena_no)){
        $cena_no = '0';
    }

    $_SESSION['sort'] = $_POST;                     
    $per_page = $default;
    $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1;
    $rows = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM zirglietas_pardod WHERE cena BETWEEN $cena_no AND $cena_lidz");
    $pages = mysql_num_rows($rows);
    $pages = ceil($pages / $per_page);
    $querystring = "";

    foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
        if ($key != "page") $querystring .= "$key=$value&amp;";
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM zirglietas_pardod WHERE cena BETWEEN $cena_no AND $cena_lidz LIMIT " . (($page - 1) * $per_page) . ", ".$per_page."");
    echo '<script>window.location.href = "pardod.php?page=1";</script>';
}
```

Session code

```
if(isset($_SESSION['sort'])) {

    $cena_no = $_SESSION['sort']['fl_cena_no'];
    $cena_lidz = $_SESSION['sort']['fl_cena_lidz'];

    if(empty($cena_lidz)){
        $cena_lidz = '99999999999999999999999999999999';
    }

    if(empty($cena_no)){
        $cena_no = '0';
    }

    $per_page = $default;
    $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1;
    $rows = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM zirglietas_pardod WHERE cena BETWEEN $cena_no AND $cena_lidz");
    $pages = mysql_num_rows($rows);
    $pages = ceil($pages / $per_page);
    $querystring = "";

    foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
        if ($key != "page") $querystring .= "$key=$value&amp;";
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM zirglietas_pardod WHERE cena BETWEEN $cena_no AND $cena_lidz LIMIT " . (($page - 1) * $per_page) . ", ".$per_page."");
}
```

When I post price range, after that I need to order data asc or desc, I create form for sort asc or desc, but I cant change session data.

This I use for sort data, but its not working when I start price range session.
Sessions starts, but nothings changes.

```
if(isset($_POST['cena_asc'])) {
    $cena_asc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['input_asc']);
    $_SESSION['cena_asc'] = $_POST;
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM zirglietas_pardod ORDER BY cena $cena_asc LIMIT " . (($page - 1) * $per_page) . ", ".$per_page."");
    echo '<script>window.location.href = "?page=1";</script>';
}

if(isset($_SESSION['cena_asc'])) {
    $cena_asc = $_SESSION['cena_asc']['input_asc'];
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM zirglietas_pardod ORDER BY cena $cena_asc LIMIT " . (($page - 1) * $per_page) . ", ".$per_page."");
}
```

Comment: try to wrap php vars inside sql qith ''

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM zirglietas_pardod WHERE cena BETWEEN '$cena_no' AND '$cena_lidz'");

Comment: @geek_guy Do you think something like that? $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM zirglietas_pardod WHERE cena BETWEEN $cena_no AND $cena_lidz ORDER BY cena {$_POST['cena_asc']} LIMIT " . (($page - 1) * $per_page) . ", ".$per_page.""); not working